# Help on Basics of Windows-Mobile

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile, mobile

can any one suggest me, how to learn about custom controls in c# for windows mobile,
any tutorials regarding some sample app's of windows mobile, how to create new custom control
application, owner-draw, etc..please suggest me

Thanks
Grabit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MSDN article helped me get started with custom controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms837926.aspx

Also it depends what you are wanting to do, but OpenNetCF has a set of controls that provide a lot more customisation than the standard controls in the .netcf.

For example if you want to show an image on a button and set all the colours manually their Button2 class may do everthing you need.

[Here](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/62950b65-5057-0434-d327-47ee883ccb3a.htm) is a link to the docs for the Button2 class. I'd recommend checking out the OpenNetCF [Smart Device Framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) as it has a lot of handy classes that weren't included in the .netCF.

Matt

Comment: Thanks, but i needed some more examples were do i get,
i dont wanna use opennetCF

Comment: As Henk mentioned, the principles are the same as the desktop framework and there are heaps of samples out there. What specifically are you trying to achieve?